# WPF Binding polyline points

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF. Is there a possibility that the points of the polyline in XAML 
connected in such a way as is possible with the line in the example below. 
The same problem is also a mini-language. Thanks

```
<Line Name="line" Fill="#FFDA2828" Stroke="Black"
           X1="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}" 
           Y1="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox2}" 
           X2="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox3}" 
           Y2="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox4}" 
  Visibility ="Visible"  StrokeThickness="2"
  StrokeDashArray="2,2,2,2">
</Line>
```

Comment: this will work ,but a converter or a viewmodel is recommended to proxy the binding

Comment: Yes it is possible. The sample that you show, works correctly. What are your doubts?

Comment: Yes it is possible with Line, but I want with Polyline, and also in mini language.

Answer (score 0):

this will work ,but a converter or a viewmodel is recommended to proxy the binding
anyway I've added  a tester
as the text change the line is update 
you will get some errors in text-> double conversions

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox3" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox4" Width="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
        <Line Name="line" Fill="#FFDA2828" Stroke="Black"
       X1="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox1}" 
       Y1="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox2}" 
       X2="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox3}" 
       Y2="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox4}"   
   Visibility ="Visible"  StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,2,2,2">
        </Line>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```